# AWK automatically rounds off numbers during multiplication

Tags: awk, rounding

I try to execute the exercise

> f) For the input file table.txt, calculate and display the product of
> numbers in the last field of each line. Consider space as the field
> separator for this file.

from https://learnbyexample.github.io/learn_gnuawk/awk-introduction.html#exercises. My solution is the following:

```
awk 'BEGIN{prod=1} {prod *= $NF} END{print prod}' table.txt
```

but when I run it, I get `-882` instead of `-923.16`.
The full output is the following:

```
andrii@andrii-VirtualBox:~/git/learn_gnuawk/exercises$ cat table.txt
brown bread mat hair 42
blue cake mug shirt -7
yellow banana window shoes 3.14
andrii@andrii-VirtualBox:~/git/learn_gnuawk/exercises$ awk 'BEGIN{prod=1} {prod *= $NF} END{print prod}' table.txt
-882
```

It seems, the number `3.14` is automatically rounded off to `3`. I can't understand, why does this happen. Moreover, my solution is almost identical to the solution from the author(s) of the exercise (https://learnbyexample.github.io/learn_gnuawk/Exercise_solutions.html) and it also outputs `-882` on my PC. I use Kubuntu 20.04.

UPD. I found out that the problem is with **mawk** which is used in my system by default, while **gawk** returns the correct result.

Comment: what is your `awk` version? This is not the expected behavior.

Comment: Your `locale` seems to be set to recognize `,` instead of `.`. Change `3.14` to `3,14` and it should work.

Comment: @AndreWildberg thank you, replacing `.` with `,` really worked in my case. On the other hand, it is not OK that the same AWK program produce different results depending on the locale.

Comment: Depends on how e.g. `mawk` was compiled. They have a ton of compile-options  and it might have been a left-over binary from another install or imported from somewhere.

Comment: Lol, the solution worked for **mawk** but now **gawk** outputs `-882` xD

Comment: Changing the locale for numbers to en_US in settings solved the problem for me for both `gawk` and `mawk`.

Comment: @АндрійНемченко producing different results for given input data depending on the locale is the whole point of a locale setting. Set `LC_ALL=C` (or equivalently `LC_ALL=POSIX`) if that locale correctly defines how your input should be interpreted.. Read the gawk documentation on decimal points for more info, https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Locale-influences-conversions.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the locale for numbers to `en_US` in settings solved the problem for me for both `gawk` and `mawk`.